# Why it is not possible to create a class that extends OnTouchListener

Tags: java, android, oop

Android SDK has an interface in `TouchEvent`. (`android.view.View.OnTouchListener`)
I don't know why the following line fails. (and Eclipse notices error at `OnTouchListener`)

```
public class TouchHandler extends OnTouchListener{
```

And it works if change to:

```
public interface TouchHandler extends OnTouchListener{
```

It means that I cannot create a class that extends `OnTouchListener`. Can somebody explain why?

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use TouchHandler implements OnTouchListener

extending an interface is only possible when defining an interface (ie:extending a contract)
implementing an interface is the java way to have a class provide code for methods of an interface. (ie: defining how the contract is handled)

Answer (score 7):

Instead of

```
public class TouchHandler extends OnTouchListener{
```

use implements

```
public class TouchHandler implements OnTouchListener{
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
public class TouchHandler implements OnTouchListener{
```

It is Java's way of playing with `interface`. Go through this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html), it will help you to clear your confusion.
Few points to clear you confusion
1. A `class` should/can implement `interface`.
2. A `interface` can extend other `interface`.

Answer (score 1):

**OnTouchListener** is an interface and therefore should be implemented, not extended.
You want to *implement* **OnTouchListener** by saying:

```
public class TouchHandler implements OnTouchListener{}
```

Answer (score 0):

only an `interface` can extend other interfaces

```
public interface B {}
public interface C extends B {}
```

if you want to use the `interface` for your class, use `implements`

```
public class A implements C {}
```